# How to deal with cookie pop ups when scraping various websites using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, cookies

I am trying to scrape ~10k different urls, using Scrapy with Selenium. At some websites, all I can scrape is the cookie pop-up. How to handle those pop-ups in general? Can the selenium driver accept all cookies by default, so that the cookie pop-up would not render? Navigating the pop-ups with selectors seems impossible, as they differ from page to page.

Comment: there is NO one, universal method to show pop-ups - so there is NO one, universal method to close them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different websites are built using different components following different architecture. Some websites may use [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) where as some other may use [Ember.js](https://www.emberjs.com/).

So in these cases the effective [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) to locate the <kbd>Accept All</kbd> button on different website is ideally bound to be different.

Hence there can be no generic solution to accept all cookies by default across all websites.